# tkinter button is not giving the correct parameter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am practicing tkinter, and i'm stuck with a problem.

i need to make a few buttons inside a for loop, and give it a command based on the iteration of the loop.

but no matter what  button i press, the output is always 'd'.
this is a simplified version:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def write(n):
    print(n)

indexes = ['a','b','c','d']

for i in range(len(indexes)):
    button = Button(root, text=indexes[i], command=lambda:write(indexes[i]))
    button.grid(row=0, column=i)

root.mainloop()
```

does anybody know what to do? thanks

Comment: Isn't it because the command `lambda:write(indexes[i])` is only evaluated when a button is pressed and therefore it executes `lambda:write('d')` because `3` was the last value of `i` causing it to return `d`.

Comment: that makes sense, il try to edit that

Comment: `command=lambda i=i:write(indexes[i])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def write(n):
    print(n)

indexes = ['a','b','c','d']

for i in range(len(indexes)):
    button = Button(root, text=indexes[i], command = lambda i=i:write(indexes[i]))
    button.grid(row=0, column=i)

root.mainloop()
```